# asp.net 5: Bind attribute with Include parameter - include is not a valid named attribute argument

Tags: attributes, model-binding, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I write code from the article and and there is:

```
public IActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Imie,Nazwisko,Stanowisko,Wiek")] Pracownik pracownik)
{
    blablablab
}
```

I want to compile but it shows error.

```
 include is not a valid named attribute argument.
```

But in the internet I saw a code similar to my code.
Someone explain to me what's going on?
Of course, I am using asp.net 5.

Comment: Show the full namespace of the `Bind` attribute

Comment: this attribute is in the "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Asp.Net Core, the `Include` property no longer has a setter. You need to pass the list of bound properties using the constructor:

```
public BindAttribute(params string[] include)
{
    Include = include;
}
```

And in your case:

```
public IActionResult Create([Bind("Imie","Nazwisko","Wiek")] Pracownik pracownik)
```

Comment: This is excellent! Combined with nameof(), we can bind with no magic strings.

Comment: In other words, "Just remove the `Include =`"